# Simple Injector with Async Form Factories

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, factory-pattern, simple-injector

**Background**

I'm creating a Winforms application that has an "AccountManagementView" form. Every time the form is created, immediately after a long task takes place. My goal is that I create the form first, and make it so that the user can interact with the form while it is performing the long task.

**Solution (so far)**

My strategy so far is to make the form's constructor private, and instead use a async factory method to create the form. After the form is created, the factory method then starts the long task.

```
public partial class AccountManagementView : Form, IAccountManagementView
{
    private AccountManagementView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static async Task<AccountManagementView> CreateAsync()
    {
        AccountManagementView view = new AccountManagementView();
        await view.LongTask();
        return view;
    }

    private async Task LongTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        this.lblTitle.Text = "Account Management - Loaded";
    }
}
```

**Question**

How do I register this factory with the IoC container Simple Injector? I've tried to register the form via:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<AccountManagementView>(AccountManagementView.CreateAsync());
```

With that attempt, I'm getting the following error message: "cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Dispatch.UI.Windows.Views.Account.AccountManagementView'"

Comment: Since you want user interaction, I think that what you want is not making things async, but simply spin up the long operation as a background task.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. I thought that using await/async was essentially making that a background task. Are you talking about using the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?ppud=4)? What is the different from a technical perspective? Is what I'm trying to do with await/async not possible?

Comment: But basically, you have a method that returns `Task<T>` but you are registering `T`. You should register `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

try  `async Task<AccountManagementView> CreateAsync()` change to `AccountManagementView CreateAsync()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use 'await' in a method that isn't marked as 'async'.

Comment: Task<AccountManagementView>  to  AccountManagementView, keep async.